# asp.net C# prevent user from leaving any of the two dropdownlists empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to update database table according to two dropdownlists value,

and I want to prevent the user from leaving any of the two dropdownlists empty

but the problem is it only check the first dropdownlist if it was empty

for example if I fill the first dropdownlist  and left the second one empty it will update the update database table and will not prevent the user from leaving the second one empty

```
   if(DropDownList_pc.SelectedItem.Value != "0" || DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value != "0")

                if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
                {
                    string sql = "update users_table set user_pc = 'yes'";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "done');", true);

                }
                else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
                {
                    string sql = "update users_table set user_pc = 'no'";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "done');", true);

                }


                if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
                {
                    string sql = "update users_table set user_laptop = 'yes'";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "done');", true);

                }
                else if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
                {
                    string sql = "update users_table set user_laptop = 'no'";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "done');", true);

                }
          }
       else{
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "you have to fill all feilds');", true);
        }
```

Comment: why not use a validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of your dropdowns doesn't depend on each other you just need to fix your condition to use the AND operator like this:

```
if(DropDownList_pc.SelectedItem.Value != "0" && DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
```

Comment: that was very easy I am not sure why I didn't try "and", thanks